# ¿Como encuentro letras iguales en diagonales de matriz java?

Tags: java, matriz

Buen día, tengo una matriz de String de 6x6 y necesito encontrar 4 letras iguales consecutivas en el sentido de las diagonales, si las encuentra da true, el tema es que cuando recorro la diagonal principal y las que estan por debajo de ella me busca bien y me da true, pero cuando recorro las diagonales por encima de la diagonal principal me da false. adjunto el código. Desde ya gracias.
como se ve en el código la matriz la he llenado yo a mano, después vienen los los dos for, no que recorre la diagonal principal y las que estan por debajo y posteriormente el otro for que recorre las diagonales por encima de la diagonal principal. las letras que puede buscar son AAAA, GGGG, TTTT o CCCC

```
public class Matriz_diagonal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String m[][] = {{"A", "T", "G", "C", "G", "A"},
                        {"C", "A", "G", "G", "G", "C"},
                        {"T", "T", "A", "T", "G", "T"},
                        {"A", "G", "A", "A", "G", "G"},
                        {"C", "C", "C", "C", "T", "A"},
                        {"T", "C", "A", "C", "T", "G"}};

        //este for recorre e imprime la matriz de string
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++) {

                System.out.print(m[i][j]);
                System.out.print(" ");

            }
            System.out.println(" ");

        }
        System.out.println(" ");


        boolean hay = false;
        boolean hay2= false;
        
        //este for recorre la diagonal principal y todas las que esten por debajo
        for (int i = 5-2; i >= 0; i--) {
            
            //inicio la variable en false para que a cada vuelta de bucle se inicialize en false
            hay = false;
            for (int j = 0; j <= 5-3; j++) {

                int k = j + i;

                if (k > 5) {
                    break;
                }

                if (m[i][j] == "A" || m[i][j] == "G" || m[i][j] == "T" || m[i][j] == "C") {

                    if (m[i][j] == m[i + 1][j+1] && m[i][j] == m[i + 2][j+2] && m[i][j] == m[i + 3][j+3]) {

                        hay = true;

                    }
                }

                System.out.print(m[k][i]);
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(hay);
        System.out.println("");
        
        
        //este for recorre las diagonales superiores o sea arriba de la diagonal principal
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5-3; i++) {
            
            //inicio la variable en false para que a cada vuelta de bucle se inicialize en false
            hay2= false; 
            
            for (int j = 0; j <= 5-2; j++) {

                int k = j + i;

                if (k > 5) {
                    break;
                }
                
                if (m[i][j] == "A" || m[i][j] == "G" || m[i][j] == "T" || m[i][j] == "C") {

                    if (m[i][j] == m[i][j+1] && m[i][j] == m[i][j+2] && m[i][j] == m[i][j+3]) {

                        hay2 = true;

                    }
                }

                System.out.print(m[j][k]);
                System.out.print(" ");

            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(hay2);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Viendo que solo preguntas por encontrar las diagonales y estas van de izquierda a derecha pues me limitaré solo a eso.

Resulta que para ver todas las diagonales de la matriz cuadrada solo debes analizar la tercera parte de la matriz, es decir el límite superior izquierdo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen que te pongo muestra con marcas amarillas solamente la parte de la matriz que debes analizar, por tanto:

```
    int contA = 0;
    int contC = 0;
    int contG = 0;
    int contT = 0;
    boolean diagonal = false;
    String[][] matriz = {{"A", "T", "G", "C", "G", "A"},
                         {"C", "A", "G", "G", "G", "C"},
                         {"T", "T", "A", "T", "G", "T"},
                         {"A", "G", "A", "A", "G", "G"},
                         {"C", "C", "C", "C", "T", "A"},
                         {"T", "C", "A", "C", "T", "G"}};

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (matriz[i][j] == matriz[i + 1][ j + 1] &&
                matriz[i][j] == matriz[i + 2][ j + 2] &&
                matriz[i][j] == matriz[i + 3][ j + 3])
            {
                diagonal = true;

                if (matriz[i][j] == "A")
                {
                    contA++;
                }
                    else if (matriz[i][j] == "C")
                {
                    contC++;
                }
                    else if (matriz[i][j] == "G")
                {
                    contG++;
                }
                    else if (matriz[i][j] == "T")
                {
                    contT++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (diagonal)
    {
        System.out.println(String.format("Diagonales de A: %s", contA));
        System.out.println(String.format("Diagonales de C: %s", contC));
        System.out.println(String.format("Diagonales de G: %s", contG));
        System.out.println(String.format("Diagonales de T: %s", contT));
    }
```

En este algoritmo lo que se hace es hacer dos **ciclos for anidados** que solamente van a recorrer un pedazo de la matriz, ya que no hace falta recorrerla completo. Posteriormente se pregunta si existen cuatro caracteres iguales en forma de diagonal, de ser cierto se le da el valor de **true** a la **variable diagonal** y entonces se pregunta para tener más información cual es la letra que conforma la diagonal, de ser **A** se incrementa **contA**, de ser **C** se incremente **contC**, de ser **G** se incrementa **contG** y de ser **T** se incrementa **contT**. Después de salir de los **ciclos for** se pregunta si la **variable diagonal** es **true**, de ser cierto quiere decir que hay al menos una diagonal en la matriz, entonces procedemos e imprimimos la cantidad de diagonales **A**, **C**, **G** y **T** en caso de existir.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer con un for, básicamente hay que guardar los valores de las diagonales, entonces simplemente guardas el valor inicial y lo comparas, si es siguiente donde te posicionas es igual al anterior entonces lo cuentas y así en caso contrario reinicias el contador y guardas ahora el valor de la letra diferente.

Te dejo la solución en javascript, pero debería ser sencillo pasarla a Java

```js
let matrix = [["A", "T", "G", "C", "G", "A"],
     ["C", "A", "G", "G", "G", "C"],
   ["T", "T", "A", "T", "G", "T"],
   ["A", "G", "A", "A", "G", "G"],
   ["C", "C", "C", "C", "T", "A"],
   ["T", "C", "A", "C", "T", "G"]];
   
console.log(validDiagonal(matrix));

function valida(){
  let res = document.getElementById('resp');
  validDiagonal(matrix) ? res.innerHTML="true" : res.innerHTML = "false";
}

function validDiagonal(matrix){
        let pivot = matrix.length - 1;
    let ant1 = '';
    let ant2 = '';
    let value1 = 0;
    let value2 = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
        //Validamos que sea el inicio y metemos las letras en las diagonales
      if(ant1 == ''){
        ant1 = matrix[i][i];
      }
      if(ant2 == ''){
        ant2 = matrix[pivot][pivot];
      }
      //Iniciamos el recorrido al fial puede ocurrior
      if(ant1 != ''){
        if(ant1 == matrix[i][i]){//Es el mismo que el aterior para la diagonal principal
            value1 ++;
        }else{
            ant1 = matrix[i][i];
            value1 = 0;
        }
      }
      //Hacemos lo mismo para el segundo valor
      if(ant2 != ''){
        if(ant2 == matrix[pivot][pivot]){//Es el mismo que el aterior para la diagonal principal
            value2 ++;
        }else{
            ant2 = matrix[pivot][pivot];
            value2 = 0;
        }
      }
      //Por ultmo retornamos false si ya existen las 4
      if(value1 == 4 || value2 == 4){
        return true;
      }
      pivot--;
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="valida()">Validar</button>
<div id="resp"></div>
```