# ¿Cómo detectar más de una secuencia de cuatro letras iguales y consecutivas en una Matriz NxN?

Tags: php, array

No logro resolver este ejercicio tengo una matriz de NxN como la siguiente:

[image: secuencia_letras]

Debo desarrollar una función que debe de recibir por parámetro un array como el siguiente

```
dna = array("ATGCGA","CAGTGC","TTATGT","AGAAGG","CCCCTA","TCACTG")
```

El punto es recórrelo y **encontrar todas las coincidencias posibles de 4 letras iguales y consecutivas** como la imagen de la matriz que he publicado en la pregunta,
**Como encontrar todas las coincidencias posibles horizontal vertical oblicua?**

Las letras de los Strings solo pueden ser: (A,T,C,G).

Hasta el momento logre desarrollar esta función que solo verifica la secuencia de las cuatros letras iguales
**en este caso es la C, con lo cual imprimo echo "iguales
";**
con esto obtengo una busqueda horizontal **como podria detectar la secuencia oblicua y vertical de la matriz?**

Por favor alguna sugerencia?.

```
<?php
$dna = array(
    array("A", "T", "G", "C", "G", "A"),
    array("C", "A", "G", "T", "G", "C"),
    array("T", "T", "A", "T", "G", "T"),
    array("A", "G", "A", "A", "G", "G"),
    array("C", "C", "C", "C", "T", "A"),
    array("T", "C", "A", "C", "T", "G"),
);
function verificar($dna)
{
    $fu = 0;
    foreach ($dna as $x) {
        for ($i = 0, $j = 1; $i < count($x); $i++, $j++) {
            if ($j < count($x)) {
                if ($x[$i] == $x[$j])
                    $fu++;
            }
        }

        if ($fu >= 4) {
            echo "iguales<br>";
            $fu = 0;
        } else
            echo "diferentes<br>";
    }
}
verificar($dna);
```

Comment: Cuando dices oblicua, ¿solo es la diagonal principal, o también la diagonal secundaria y las demás subdiagonales, por ejemplo `(0,1), (1, 2), (2, 3),...`?

Comment: @aeportugal, para este caso solo la diagonal principal, aunque no he pensado en las demas diagonales en ese caso como seria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se que no es buena practica abrir otra respuesta existiendo el botón de editar, pero considero que la respuesta anterior es suficientemente válida y buena como para que quede de referencia.

En esta versión, la función `consecutivos()` quedará así:

```
function consecutivos($array, $cant=4) {
    $value = null;
    $count = 1;
    $amount = array();
    foreach($array as $elem) {
        if($elem == $value) {
            $count++;
        } else {
            $value = $elem;
            $count = 1;
        }
        if($count == $cant) {
            $amount[$elem] = isset($amount[$elem]) ? ++$amount[$elem] : 1;
        }
    }
    return $amount;
}
```

Esta vez devolverá un array que tendrá qué elemento se repite y cuántas veces, por ejemplo:

```
// $amount = array("A"=>1, "G"=>2, etc...)
```

Ahora la función principal irá enviándole fila por fila a la función anterior, la cual le devolverá un array parecido al descrito, o bien un array vacío (evaluado como false) si no hay coincidencias.

```
function verificar($dna) {
    $dna2 = array_map('str_split', $dna);
    $size = count($dna2);
    $transp = array_map(null, ...$dna2);
    $diag_pr = array();
    $result = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
        $count_norm = consecutivos($dna2[$i]);
        $count_tran = consecutivos($transp[$i]);
        if($count_norm) {
            $result['row'][$i] = $count_norm;
        }
        if($count_tran) {
            $result['col'][$i] = $count_tran;
        }
        $diag_pr[] = $dna2[$i][$i]; // Por ciclo se agrega un elem de la diagonal principal
    }
    $count_diag = consecutivos($diag_pr);
    if($count_diag) {
        $result['diag'][0] = $count_diag;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Esta función devolverá un array con el siguiente formato (datos de ejemplo):

```
array(
    'row'=>array(
        4=>array(
            'C'=>2
        )
    ),
    'col'=>array(
        2=>array(
            'G'=>1
        ), 
        9=>array(
            'G'=>1, 
            'T'=>1
        )
    ),
    'diag'=>array(
        0=>array(
            'A'=>2
        )
    )
)
```

Usando un array más grande (10x10) para hacer la prueba:

```
$dna = array(
"ATGCGATTBG",
"CAGTGCTCAG",
"TTATGTAAGG",
"AGAAGGTTGG",
"CCCCTACCCC",
"TCACTAGCTT",
"CACGTAACTT",
"GCCAACAACT",
"AACCTGACAT",
"CCGTCCTTTT"
);
$res = verificar($dna);
```

La variable `$res` ahora tiene un array asociativo con los resultados en el formato descrito anteriormente, puedes construir una función para imprimirlos o hacer cálculos.
Por ejemplo, para imprimirlos:

```
function print_values($desc, $array) {
    foreach($array as $id_row => $values) {
        echo $desc . ' ' . $id_row;
        foreach($values as $k => $v) {
            echo ' | ' . $k . ' => ' . $v;
        }
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
}

isset($res['row']) ? print_values('Fila', $res['row']) : '';
isset($res['col']) ? print_values('Columna', $res['col']) : '';
isset($res['diag']) ? print_values('Diagonal', $res['diag']) : '';
```

La salida será:

```
Fila 4 | C => 2
Fila 9 | T => 1
Columna 4 | G => 1
Columna 9 | G => 1 | T => 1
Diagonal 0 | A => 2
```

Si quieres sumar todas las coincidencias, simplemente sumar el tercer nivel del array. Quizás puedas modificar la lógica anterior para que también devuelva ese valor, o bien crear una función nueva:

```
function sumar_coinc($array) {
    $suma = 0;
    foreach($array as $row_col_diag) {
        foreach($row_col_diag as $index) {
            foreach($index as $char=>$repeticion) {
                $suma += $repeticion;
            }
        }
    }
    return $suma;
}

echo sumar_coinc($res); // Resultado: 8
```

Comment: Gracias por volver a reformular tu respuesta ahora me a quedado más claro.

Comment: de que manera podria sumar estas busqueda de secuencias encontradas ? siguiendo con tu ejemplo: **Fila 4: C => 2
Columna 4: G => 1
Fila 9: T => 1
Columna 9: G => 1 | T => 1
Diagonal principal: A => 2** aqui deberia de tener un **total de 8 secuencias encontradas**. Podrias darme un ejemplo para sumar y totalizar las secuencias encontradas?

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz Hice algunas modificaciones para que la función principal devolviera el array resultante y así puedas hacer cálculos fuera de ella.

Comment: gracias ha funcionado perfecto!!

Answer (score 0):

Propongo crear 2 funciones. La primera es una que va a verificar si un array unidimensional tiene 4 caracteres seguidos. Cuando detecta que `$count == $cant` (o sea 4 en este caso), el ciclo se cierra y retorna `True` si encontró una coincidencia de 4 elementos consecutivos o `False` en caso contrario.

```
function consecutivos($array, $cant=4) {
    $value = null;
    $count = 1;
    foreach($array as $elem) {
        if($count == $cant) {
            break;
        } elseif(($elem == $value)) {
            $count++;
        } else {
            $value = $elem;
            $count = 1;
        }
    }
    return ($count == $cant);
}
```

Con esa función creada, ahora es cuestión de extraer los subarrays para enviárselos. La "matriz de columnas" es simplemente la [matriz traspuesta](https://www.google.com/search?q=matriz%20traspuesta) de la original. Hay multipes formas de [transponer una matriz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797251/transposing-multidimensional-arrays-in-php), en este caso usé la instrucción: `array_map(null, ...$dna);`

Con esa información se puede crear, ahora si, la función principal.
En el `if` se envia fila por fila tanto de la matriz normal como de su traspuesta a la función anterior. Si alguno devuelve `True`, entonces el ciclo se rompe porque hay 4 valores repetidos. Mientras tanto, cada elemento de la diagonal principal se va acumulando en `$diag_pr`. Obviamente, si el ciclo se rompe antes de terminar, también la diagonal principal quedará a "medio hacerse", pero no importa, porque el resultado ya será `True`.
Finalmente se devuelve un booleano entre lo calculado en las filas, columnas y su diagonal.
[Nota] Esta función solo verifica si hay consecutivos, no provee información en donde se dio la coincidencia. Adicional, la matriz tiene que ser cuadrada NxN.

```
function verificar($dna) {
    $size = count($dna);
    $transp = array_map(null, ...$dna);
    $diag_pr = [];
    $result = False;
    for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
        if(consecutivos($dna[$i]) or consecutivos($transp[$i])) {
            $result = True;
            break;
        }
        $diag_pr[] = $dna[$i][$i]; // Por ciclo se agrega un elem de la diagonal principal
    }
    return ($result or consecutivos($diag_pr));
}
```

Haciendo pruebas:

```
var_dump(verificar($dna)); // bool(true)
```

Si quisieras saber dónde se dio la coincidencia tendrás que deconstruir el `if` que está dentro del `for` de la función principal en varios `if` para ir comparando en dónde la función `consecutivos` devuelve `True` para cada caso.

Comment: Gracias por responder a mi pregunta según entiendo la solución que planteas busca la primer coincidencia y devuelve true es así ?. Lo que pregunto es como buscar dentro de la tabla NxN (segunda imagen) **todas las coincidencias posibles de 4 letras iguales y consecutivas**

Comment: mi función debe de recibir por parámetro un array como el siguiente  ```dna = array("ATGCGA","CAGTGC","TTATGT","AGAAGG","CCCCTA","TCACTG")```,**el punto es recórrelo y encontrar todas las coincidencias posibles de 4 letras iguales y consecutivas**  como la segunda imagen de la matriz que he publicado en la pregunta, encontrar todas las **coincidencias posibles horizontal vertical oblicua-principal** ahí es donde me pierdo en el intento.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/426349/como-encuentro-letras-iguales-en-diagonales-de-matriz-java/430902#430902 entra aqui es en java pero las respuestas se parecen bastante a lo que buscas

Comment: @Japv Gracias lo voy a revisar!